# iOS/Swift: What is the difference to share PDF file/data via UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, file, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am loading pdf data from remote url and display them in WKWebView.

Now I am adding sharing functionality and I am considering what is the difference to share this downloaded data as **Data** and as **File** stored in /tmp location on disk.

It seems that both ways works

A)

1. get Data
2. create UIActivityViewController with activityItems: [pdfData]

B)

1. get Data
2. save Data in /tmp directory
3. get URL to tmp file
4. create UIActivityViewController with activityItems: [pdfFileUrl]

   ```
   private func sharePDFData(from barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
       guard let pdfData = self.pdfData else { return }
       let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)
       activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = barButtonItem
       activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
       self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

And

```
      private func sharePDFFile(from barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
        guard let pdfFileUrl = self.pdfTempFileUrl() else { return }
        print("PDF temp file url:", pdfFileUrl)

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pdfFileUrl.path) {

            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfFileUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = barButtonItem
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

The only difference I can see is that using temporary file storage I can change filename of the shared PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

According to me I have same kind of question when I share one file which I downloaded and store in document directory and open in UIActivityViewController and while sharing the file it will show me default application which Apple recommended for sharing, but I need other third party Apps to use that file for sharing , I Use UIDocumentInteractionController and it will show me all other related application for sharing the files.
I guess for sharing UIActivityViewController provides default application list to share compare to UIDocumentInteractionController.